# Is it possible to use wro4j to parse files and generate 'sass' versions of css without applying any bundling?

Tags: maven, configuration, sass, bundling-and-minification, wro4j

We are trying to run a SASS parser over our CSS files as part of our Maven build, but do not want them to be bundled together at the same time during this phase of the Maven life cycle.

However, I cannot see a simple way of using wro4J to do this without specifying each individual file as its own bundlem which just doesn't feel right.  Have I missed some configurationm or is bundling so much at the core of the design of wro4J that it must be used like this?

Comment: Maybe you can use [`SassCssProcessor`](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/source/browse/wro4j-extensions/src/main/java/ro/isdc/wro/extensions/processor/css/SassCssProcessor.java) class directly? You'll have to wrap it up in your own maven plugin thou.

Comment: Well, it's an idea, but I'd probably just use one of the alternative  maven plugins - I was just hoping to keep the build as simple as possible by just using wro4j and hoping I'd missed some capability it has.

Comment: This feature is not supported by wro4j yet, but it is planned to be added in future. In the meantime, you can use SassCssProcessor with a custom maven plugin which just applies the processor on each resource from a configured folder. The link to the issue describing the feature you need: http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/issues/detail?id=583&start=100. Feel free to comment here or to follow its progress.

Comment: Thanks for that Alex - very helpful to know

Answer (score 1):

> This feature is not supported by wro4j yet, but it is planned to be added in future. In the meantime, you can use SassCssProcessor with a custom maven plugin which just applies the processor on each resource from a configured folder. The link to the issue describing the feature you need: https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j/issues/583